# Does outlook provide API's to figure out who accepted or declined an invite?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, outlook, ruby-on-rails-5, outlook-restapi, microsoft-graph-mail

I have created a rails app. It sends emails to customers based on some parameters. The customers only use outlook as their mail app. The customers may accept/decline the invite. If a customer declines the invite, they should inform me through the rails app that they have declined the invite. But in some cases they do not communicate this information.

So does Outlook (Mac, Windows, Web, Mobile) provide API's to know if a person has declined the meeting invite sent by my rails app ?

-Thanks,

Vinit

Comment: The Outlook object model (Outlook for desktop on Windows) provides the [AppointmentItem.ResponseStatus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.appointmentitem.responsestatus) property which returns an `OlResponseStatus` constant indicating the overall status of the meeting for the current user for the appointment. Look for something similar in Graph API.

Answer (score 0):

The attendees collection will provide status for each attendee. Keep in mind that it is usually only available to the organizer, and to all attendees on some Office 365 mailboxes.

You can see it in [OutlookSpy](https://www.dimastr.com/outspy) (I am its author) and the [Graph documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/responsestatus?view=graph-rest-1.0).

[image]